# How to get text in td web-table with Selinium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I am trying to extract text from a td webtable but have not been able to locate the element; the table has no class or id so I have attempted xpath without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/primertool.cgi?ctg_time=1585700551&job_key=9P4rCho2F54woA2lAMUpl3reOKVXzSO4Vg&CheckStatus=Check")

pair_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("html/body/div[@id ='wrap']/div[@id='content-wrap']/div[@id='content']/div[contains(@class, ' ')]/div[contains(@class, ' ')]/div[contains(@class, 'ui-helper-resert')]/div[@id ='alignInfo']/div[@id ='alignments']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"))

print(pair_1.text)

#OR

pair_1.get_attribute("innerHTML")

print(pair_1)
```

Return the following error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

A simpler xpath

```
pair_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")
print(pair_1.text)
```

Returns this

```
Looking for [chromedriver 80.0.3987.06 mac6] driver in cache 
File found in cache by path [/Users/usr/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/80.0.3987.06/mac6/chromedriver]
```

website and html
[image]
[image]

Thank you advance, I am a novice with Selenium.

Comment: try using get_attribute("innerHTML")

Comment: Great idea, but sadly `pair_1.get_attribute("innerHTML")` still gives me `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` any idea why?

Comment: Where, exactly, are you getting this error?  On the `get_attribute()` call, or the `print()` call?  If the latter, check to make sure you haven't named one of your variables `print`, thus erasing the built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try the following*

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/primertool.cgi?ctg_time=1585700551&job_key=9P4rCho2F54woA2lAMUpl3reOKVXzSO4Vg&CheckStatus=Check")
time.sleep(2)

pair_1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "#alignments > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)"
).get_attribute("innerHTML")


print(pair_1)
```

*on windows, chrome Version 80*

---

> *select the text > Right click > inspect > Right click > inspect > right click on `<td>` copy selector*
>
> [image]

---

> [image]

Comment: This is excellent, thank you so much! I also need to locate the "Reverse Primer" in the next `<tr>` as well as both "Tm's" and the "Product Length." Could you briefly explain how you were able to locate the element or provide some documentation please? Thank you again @0m3r

Comment: Thank you again for elaborating @0m3r !! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
driver.get('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/primertool.cgi?ctg_time=1585700551&job_key=9P4rCho2F54woA2lAMUpl3reOKVXzSO4Vg&CheckStatus=Check')

str1 = "Primer pair 1";
str2 = "Forward primer";
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='" +str1 +"']//following-sibling::table//th[text()='" +str2+"']//following-sibling::td[1]")))
print(el.text)
```

You can change string value.

And this error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` appear because you wrong in this line:

```
pair_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("the value"))
```

It should:

```
pair_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "the value")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying, I was wondering why I was getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of '**Forward primer**','**Reverse primer**'and '**Product length**' from the `Primer pair 1` Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `visibility_of_element_located`() and following `XPath`.

1.Create a list of items and then iterate.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

product_list=['Forward primer','Reverse primer','Product length']
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/primertool.cgi?ctg_time=1585700551&job_key=9P4rCho2F54woA2lAMUpl3reOKVXzSO4Vg&CheckStatus=Check")
for item in product_list:
    print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h2[text()='Primer pair 1']/following::table[1]//th[text()='{}']/following-sibling::td[1]".format(item)))).text)
```

**Output**:

```
GAGGGCATACCCCTCGTAGA
CTGCCGTTTTCCGTAGGACT
506
```

To get data from All Primer pairs try this.

1.Create a list of primers and then iterate.

2.Create a list of items and then iterate.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/primertool.cgi?ctg_time=1585700551&job_key=9P4rCho2F54woA2lAMUpl3reOKVXzSO4Vg&CheckStatus=Check")

list_primerpairs=['Primer pair 1','Primer pair 2','Primer pair 3','Primer pair 4','Primer pair 5']
product_list=['Forward primer','Reverse primer','Product length']
for primer in list_primerpairs:
    print(primer)
    print("===========================================")
    for item in product_list:

        print(WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h2[text()='{}']/following::table[1]//th[text()='{}']/following-sibling::td[1]".format(primer,item)))).text)
    print("==========================================")
```

**Output**:

```
Primer pair 1
===========================================
GAGGGCATACCCCTCGTAGA
CTGCCGTTTTCCGTAGGACT
506
==========================================
Primer pair 2
===========================================
AGTCCTACGGAAAACGGCAG
GCTATTCTCGCAGCTCACCA
621
==========================================
Primer pair 3
===========================================
AGGTAGTCAGTCAGGTCCCG
TGCCGTTTTCCGTAGGACTC
558
==========================================
Primer pair 4
===========================================
AGGGCATACCCCTCGTAGAT
TCTGCCGTTTTCCGTAGGAC
506
==========================================
Primer pair 5
===========================================
GGGCATACCCCTCGTAGATG
GCCGTTTTCCGTAGGACTCT
502
==========================================
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great @KunduK . Right now I am just working on getting the top hit, but this will be very useful should we choose to get more than one pair of primers. In terms of the `wait` argument, my full code goes from the previous page entering parameters to letting the tool find the pairs. I've tried wait times of 30-120 but I still keep getting `TimeoutException`

Comment: While the `WebDriverWait` doesn't work, while `time.sleep()` does.